# При загрузке файлов на сервер nginx их режет до 64кб

Tags: node.js, nginx

Загружаю изображения на сервер node js с помощью модуля multer. Без nginx'а все работает норм, а вот как его включаю начинаются странности. При загрузки файлов их размер становится 64кб, в конфиге шарился, но результата не принесло.

код самого конфига вот

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
#  multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 650;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
client_max_body_size 0;
#added
output_buffers 32 512k;
sendfile_max_chunk 128k;
postpone_output 1460;
proxy_buffering off;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 10m;
proxy_buffer_size 16k;
proxy_buffers 8 64k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout 90;
proxy_send_timeout 6000;
proxy_read_timeout 6000;
client_body_in_file_only clean;

server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;


include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip off;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

##
#My code
##
server {

        client_max_body_size 50m;
    listen localhost:80;

    location / {
         client_max_body_size 50m;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }



    location ^~ /public/ {
        root /home/www/visage_school;
    }
    location ^~ /gallery/public/ {
        root /home/www/visage_school;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Наверное это происходит из за gzip сжатия(gzip on;), http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html

Comment: Может стоит закомменченные куски конфига удалить, чтобы не засорять вопрос? ;)

Comment: поставил gzip off; , к несчастью не помогло, и как оказалось он еще и до 21кб иногда режет

Comment: начните с того, что оставьте дефолтные настройки, закомментировав весь этот конфигурационный мусор.

Comment: проблема была до этого мусора, это попытки исправить проблему, т.к. с nginx только начал разбираться то пробовал всё, что хоть как-то казалось приближенным к проблеме